# What would cause water to pulse from the faucet?

Tags: plumbing, water

What causes both hot and cold water from kitchen tap to pulsate as if getting a breath. This happens at all times of day and is most noticeable at half to full flow.

Comment: Is it a fast splutter, or a slow steady change of pressure like a throb?

Comment: Are you on a well or municipal water supply? Also, do you have a pressure reducing valve in the system?

Comment: Sounds like a pressure tank that is waterlogged or lost it’s charge.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like water hammer.  I had a similar issue with mine.  Your local hardware store should carry a device you can install on your water lines that basically has a little expansion volume to reduce the effects of water hammer.  Easy to install, solved my issue.